# How to make two colors in one window?

Tags: java, swing, colors

I want to do the same like this:

[image: the image]

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class QuizGUI {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Simple Quiz");
        frm.setLayout(null);
        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Which Animal can fly?");
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("You have selected: ");
        JLabel lblOutput = new JLabel();
        JRadioButton rCat = new JRadioButton("Cat");
        JRadioButton rBird = new JRadioButton("Bird");
        JRadioButton rFish = new JRadioButton("Fish");
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        bg.add(rCat);
        bg.add(rBird);
        bg.add(rFish);

        lbl1.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 20);
        rCat.setBounds(0, 20, 100, 20);
        rBird.setBounds(0, 40, 100, 20);
        rFish.setBounds(0, 60, 100, 20);
        lbl2.setBounds(0, 80, 200, 20);
        lblOutput.setBounds(0, 105, 200, 20);

        frm.add(lbl1);
        frm.add(rCat);
        frm.add(rBird);
        frm.add(rFish);
        frm.add(lbl2);
        frm.add(lblOutput);

        rCat.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (rCat.isSelected()) {
                    lblOutput.setText("Cat can't fly, Try again.");
                }
            }
        });

        rBird.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (rBird.isSelected()) {
                    lblOutput.setText("Bird can fly, Excellent.");
                }
            }
        });

        rFish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (rFish.isSelected()) {
                    lblOutput.setText("Cat can't fly, Try again.");
                }
            }
        });

        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setSize(350, 200);

        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want the colors of window like image the background is white and the background for choices is gray.

I tried `frame.setBackground` but doesn't work.

I tried some codes for another examples and the color was white. I don't know why the window is all gray like this:

[image: img]

Comment: Each container (typically a `JPanel`) can have a distinctive  background color, so combine them.

Comment: On a wider note: `frm.setLayout(null);` 1) Set a content pane  for a frame, if needed, but don't mess with the existing content pane (is my recommendation). Some methods when called on a frame will automatically pass through to the default content pane, others won't. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with ..

Comment: .. layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: *"I tried `frame.setBackground` but doesn't work."* Uh-yup.. *"Some methods when called on a frame will automatically pass through to the default content pane, others won't."* I think you just discovered one that won't. It's possible that method passes through to the underlying frame, which is being ***covered*** by the content pane.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted in your question:

```java
frm.setLayout(null);
```

This is not a good idea. I recommend always using a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). `JFrame` is a [top-level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). It has a content pane which, by default, is a `JPanel`. The default layout manager for the content pane is `BorderLayout`. You can refer to the source code for `JFrame` in order to confirm this.

In my opinion `BorderLayout` is suitable for your GUI. One `JPanel` is the NORTH component and it displays the question, namely **Which Animal can fly?**, the radio buttons are the CENTER component and the text **You have selected:** is the SOUTH panel.

Each `JPanel` can then have its own background color. I am using JDK 13 on Windows 10 and the default background color is gray. Hence, in the code below, I set the background color for the NORTH and SOUTH panels and leave the CENTER panel with its default background color.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class QuizGUI implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String BIRD = "Bird";
    private static final String CAT = "Cat";
    private static final String FISH = "Fish";

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel resultLabel;

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case BIRD:
                resultLabel.setText(BIRD + " can fly. Excellent.");
                break;
            case CAT:
                resultLabel.setText(CAT + " can't fly. Try again.");
                break;
            case FISH:
                resultLabel.setText(FISH + " can't fly. Try again.");
                break;
            default:
                resultLabel.setText(actionCommand + " is not handled.");
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Simple Quiz");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createQuestionPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createChoicesPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createOutcomePanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(350, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createRadioButton(String text, ButtonGroup bg, JPanel panel) {
        JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(text);
        radioButton.addActionListener(this);
        bg.add(radioButton);
        panel.add(radioButton);
    }

    private JPanel createChoicesPanel() {
        JPanel choicesPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        createRadioButton(CAT, bg, choicesPanel);
        createRadioButton(BIRD, bg, choicesPanel);
        createRadioButton(FISH, bg, choicesPanel);
        return choicesPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createOutcomePanel() {
        JPanel outcomePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5));
        outcomePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel promptLabel = new JLabel("You have selected:");
        setBoldFont(promptLabel);
        outcomePanel.add(promptLabel);
        resultLabel = new JLabel("    ");
        outcomePanel.add(resultLabel);
        return outcomePanel;
    }

    private JPanel createQuestionPanel() {
        JPanel questionPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        questionPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel("Which Animal can fly?");
        setBoldFont(questionLabel);
        questionPanel.add(questionLabel);
        return questionPanel;
    }

    private void setBoldFont(JLabel label) {
        Font boldFont = label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
        label.setFont(boldFont);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String slaf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(slaf);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException |
               IllegalAccessException |
               InstantiationException |
               UnsupportedLookAndFeelException x) {
            System.out.println("WARNING (ignored): Failed to set [system] look-and-feel");
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new QuizGUI());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a private `JPanel` called `contentPane` in your QuizGUI class. Then in your `main` method, type:

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
frm.setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

then, change all `frm.add()` with `contentPane.add()`

I hope this helped!